# Compute geodesic distances in R for all rows in data frame

Tags: r, geosphere

I have a data frame of the form

| lon1 | lat1 | lon2 | lat2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

representing coordinates of pairs of points. How do I do to calculate the geodesic distance between the pairs in a new column? There is the package `geosphere` which can do this for pairs of points of the form `distm(c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2))`. Is there a way to apply this directly to the columns?

Comment: See linked post, it is for data.table object, but the solution could be used for data.frames, too.

Answer (score 0):

With some toy data

```
library(geosphere)

dat=matrix(rnorm(3*4),3,4)

distGeo(dat[,1:2],dat[,3:4])

[1] 249363.2 134563.1 146278.5
```